# How to find all posts tagged with a certain tag that I have answered?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

More and more often, I find myself updating and fixing information in The answers I've given. But it usually takes 3-4 minutes to find a certain answer. Is there a way in which I can search all answers I've given to questions tagged with a certain tag, **that I've answered?**

take the Python tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) for instance. How would I  go about finding all answers to questions tagged with it, **that I've answered?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution was given by @yellowantphil. Simple type this in the search box of Stack Overflow:

> `[tag_to_be_used_in_search] is:a user:unique_user_id`

[Demo using Python and my user number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20is%3Aa%20user%3Ame).